# Compute $f(x)$ given $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f((n+\frac{1}{2})z)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series, inverse-problems

Let's say I have some function
$$F(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f\big(\big(n+\tfrac{1}{2}\big)z\big)$$
which I can evaluate for any $z>0$. Is there a way to recover $f$ purely by evaluations of $F$? I'm thinking there might be some inversion method similar to the Ramanujan interpolation formula, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: @Gary Thanks, this is quite helpful. To make sure, that integral should be with respect to $s$ instead of $t$, and the lhs should be $f(t)$? Also, I presume we need $c>1/2$ (or $c>1$ to avoid assuming RH) so that the integral misses the poles of $\frac{1}{2^s-1}$ and $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ right?

Comment: Yes, I corrected it: $$
f(t) = \frac{1}{{2\pi {\rm i}}}\int_{c - {\rm i}\infty }^{c + {\rm i}\infty } {\frac{{t^{ - s} }}{{(2^s  - 1)\zeta (s)}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {z^{s - 1} F(z){\rm d}z}\, {\rm d}s} .
$$ The $c$ will also depend on the behaviour of the integrand as $\operatorname{Im}(s)\to \pm\infty$.

Comment: @Gary Can u post a derivation for your formula ? Sounds interesting.

Comment: @Balajisb Start with the formula in the question, take the Mellin transform of both sides, solve for the Mellin transform of $f$, take the inverse Mellinn transform of both sides.

Comment: If one assumes that $f$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of infinity with Laurent series $f(z) = \sum_{m = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{a_m }}{{z^m }}}$, then $$
a_m  = \frac{1}{{2\pi {\rm i}}}\frac{1}{{(2^m  - 1)\zeta (m)}}\oint_{(0 + )} {t^{m - 1} F(t){\rm d}t} .$$

Comment: @Gary Thanks Gary. It works out.

Answer (score 1):

$F(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} f((n+0.5)z)$

Let $f(z) = \sum_{m \leq L} a_m z^m$ then

$$F(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \sum_{m \leq L} a_m ((n+0.5)z)^m = \sum_{n \geq 0} \sum_{m \leq L} a_m  (n+0.5)^m z^m  = \sum_{m \leq L} b_m z^m$$

We can find:
$$\implies b_m =  a_m \sum_{n \geq 0}(n+0.5)^m .$$ for $m \leq L = -2$.

But similarly solving assuming series expansion for $f(z)$ at $z=a$ is involved.

Comment: The infinite series for $b_m$ is divergent.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Fixed it to a special case.

Comment: The series for $b_m$ converges only if $m \le -2$.

Comment: +1 this is a nice idea.